# Is registering your app through iTunesConnect required to test GameKit integration?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, app-store-connect, gamekit

I'd like to add GameKit integration to my app.  I was hoping to be able to evaluate how it works.  From the [docs I found](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH5-SW15), it seems that I have to register my app through iTunes Connect first.  I'm new to the iOS development front, so maybe I'm wrong here, but it seems like registering your app in iTunes Connect is a pretty final step, and I'd like to be able to test things before going through that step.

So, I guess I have two questions:

1.) Do I have to register my app with iTunes Connect before being able to use GameKit?

2.) Am I being crazy about not wanting to register with iTunes Connect yet?  Should I stop worrying and just do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes.

2) I think so.  You can still change most stuff after registering.  The only exception I can think of at the moment is the bundle ID; if you want to change that, you have to delete the app and start over.  A couple of things about registering:

- One advantage of registering with iTunes Connect is that you get to reserve the name.  BUT if you don't upload an app within 120 days, you will lose your reserved name, and furthermore you will never be able to use that name for any app.  If you don't know what name you want, you can always register with some silly name you will never want.
- The system will ask you for an image.  Don't worry, you can give it any image of the proper size, and change it later.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I remember that registering in iTunes Connect triggers a deadline (if I recall correctly, 2 months). If you don't upload your app before that deadline, your app will be deleted and you may not use your app name anymore.

Comment: Good point; it's 4 months now; edited my answer to reflect this